# yas-expand doesn't trigger reindent in aggressive-indent-mode

Tags: indentation, yasnippet, electric-indent

I'm trying to make a call to `yas-expand` doesn't trigger `aggressive-indent`. I'm guessing this is because `yas-expand`, for some reason, doesn't trigger a call to `after-change-functions` into which `aggressive-indent--keep-track-of-changes` is added when the `aggressive-indent` package is loaded.

Is there a way to make `yas-expand` at the end trigger the correct call to `after-change-functions`?

I was thinking something like

```
(add-hook 'yas-after-exit-snippet-hook
            (lambda () (run-hooks '(after-change-functions))))
```

would do the trick but this error.

For the time being I'm using the hack

```
(add-hook 'yas-after-exit-snippet-hook
            (lambda ()
              (insert " ")
              (backward-delete-char 1)))
```

to trigger a call to `after-change-functions`.

Is there a way to manually trigger a call to `after-change-functions`?